# PowerShell: сделать выборку и отправить результат

Tags: powershell, grep

**file.txt:**

```
1 a good line
2 a line with an exception
3
4 is another line
5 a good line by deleting
6
7 all the other lines
8
9 and etc
10
```

**exlude-list.txt**

```
file\separated\with\*exception*
file\separated with\*exception with a space*
file\separated\with\*deleting*
```

Помогите, пожалуйста: необходимо из file.txt убрать строки, в которых есть слова из последнего поля exlude-list.txt, и результат отправить по почте.

Как сделать на sh/bash знаю, а вот в повершелл я слабоват.

Почему PowerShell? Потому как это часть кода, который отправляет отчёт. Сам отчёт длинный, потому отправляется упакованным в виде вложения:

```
(Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpserver -UseSsl -From $from -To 
$recipient -Subject $subject -Body $body -Encoding utf8 -Credential 
$Credential -Attachments $file).
```

В `$body` хочу вставить результат "выборки".